# update listview when i remove item on it

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, navigation-drawer

I'm very newly into this programming language can somebody help me what to do.

## Here is my screenshot# https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLCr7.jpg

the listview is not updating if i click the home fragment where listview contains

## MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navLogout;
String[] navMenuTitles;
TypedArray navMenuIcons;

ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.nav_drawer_items_not_login);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // login
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // register
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // classic brownies
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // cupcakes
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // cookies
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // feedback
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // about
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(5, -1)));

    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, // nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
                                // accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
                                // accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        displayView(0);

    }

}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item

        displayView(position);

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title

    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Fragment newFragment = new AboutFragment();
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:
        Toast.makeText(this, "search selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        break;

    case R.id.action_shoppingcart:




            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();

            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, newFragment,
                    "AboutFragment");

            transaction.commit();

            getActionBar().setTitle("Shopping cart");



        return true;

    default:
        break;

    }
    return true;
}

/* *
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);

    menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_shoppingcart).setVisible(!drawerOpen);

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:

        fragment = new HomeFragment();

        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new LoginFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new RegisterFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new ClassicBrowniesFragment();

        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new CupcakesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new CookiesFragment();
        break;
    case 6:
        fragment = new FeedbackFragment();
        break;
    case 7:
        fragment = new AboutFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }

    else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
}
```

## HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {

String[] member_names;
TypedArray product_icons;
String[] statues;
String[] contactType;

List<RowItem> rowItems;
ListView mylistview;
CustomAdapter myadapter;
CustomAdapter newadapter;

EditText editsearch;

public HomeFragment() {
}

View rootView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

    member_names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Member_names);

    product_icons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.product_icons);

    statues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.statues);

    for (int i = 0; i < member_names.length; i++) {
        RowItem item = new RowItem(member_names[i],
                product_icons.getResourceId(i, -1), statues[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);
    }

    mylistview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

    mylistview.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    //
    final CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), rowItems);
    mylistview.setAdapter(adapter);
    product_icons.recycle();
    mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    mylistview.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);

    mylistview.invalidateViews();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    this.setRetainInstance(true);

    return rootView;

}

public void updateList(List adapter) {
    mylistview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    mylistview.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    String member_name = rowItems.get(position).getMember_name();
    int product_icons = rowItems.get(position).getProfile_pic_id();
    String status = rowItems.get(position).getStatus();

    RowItem item = rowItems.get(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeFragment.class);
    intent.putExtra("member_name", member_name);
    intent.putExtra("product_icons", product_icons);
    intent.putExtra("status", status);

    rowItems.remove(item);

    newadapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), rowItems);
    mylistview.setAdapter(newadapter);

    newadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            "Added to Cart: " + member_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

## CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

HomeFragment home = new HomeFragment();

Context context;
List<RowItem> rowItems;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> rowItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItems = rowItems;

}

public CustomAdapter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rowItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rowItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

/* private view holder class */
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView product_icons;
    TextView member_name;
    TextView status;
    Button addtocart;
}

ViewHolder holder = null;

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.member_name = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.member_name);
        holder.product_icons = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.product_icons);
        holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        holder.addtocart = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.btnaddtocart);

        RowItem row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

        holder.product_icons.setImageResource(row_pos.getProfile_pic_id());
        holder.member_name.setText(row_pos.getMember_name());
        holder.status.setText(row_pos.getStatus());
        holder.addtocart.setText(" add to cart");

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    return convertView;
    }

}
```

## RowItem.java

```
 public class RowItem {

 private String member_name;
 private int profile_pic_id;
 private String status;



 public RowItem(String member_name, int profile_pic_id, String status) {

  this.member_name = member_name;
  this.profile_pic_id = profile_pic_id;
  this.status = status;



 }

 public String getMember_name() {
  return member_name;
 }

 public void setMember_name(String member_name) {
  this.member_name = member_name;
 }

 public int getProfile_pic_id() {
  return profile_pic_id;
 }

 public void setProfile_pic_id(int profile_pic_id) {
  this.profile_pic_id = profile_pic_id;
 }

 public String getStatus() {
  return status;
 }

 public void setStatus(String status) {
  this.status = status;
 }

 }
```

Please help me with this thing for my software engineering subject i hope anyone can help me.

Comment: First explain how it should work please. Do we have to find out ourselves by digging through all this code? `the listview is not updating ` ? The item was gone so the listview was ok.

Comment: i want to see the listview is still updated if i go to other fragment and back again to the home fragment where listview is contain.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are just removing the view that holds the data and not actually changing the underlying data set. You call `rowItems.remove()` when you want the item removed but remember when the fragment is reloaded like when you click on the `Home` navigation option that the code in `HomeFragment.createView()` is run.

In that code you can see that the rowItems is initialized here

```
member_names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Member_names);

for (int i = 0; i < member_names.length; i++) {
    RowItem item = new RowItem(member_names[i],
            product_icons.getResourceId(i, -1), statues[i]);
    rowItems.add(item);
}
```

So unless you are removing the item from the `Member_names` array resource when it is deleted then it will appear every time you recreate the fragment.

Comment: yes sir, i don't know how to update the variables or string array something like that. :( sorry for being beginner.

Comment: It depends on if you want the item permanently deleted or not. If you don't want the item to ever show up again even after restarting the whole application then I think you will have to use something other than an Android resource file because I don't think they can be edited programmatically, or at least not very easily.

Comment: i want to delete item only in runtime but when i restart the application it goes back again.

Comment: There are several options for storing programmatic data in android as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). For your purposes the shared preferences is probably the best option.

Comment: Ok then you don't necessarily need any of the options in the article I just posted. You just need to come up with a way to not run the initialization code I posted in my answer every time in `onCreateView()`. There are many ways to achieve this, but I believe if you run it in the `onCreate()` method of the fragment then it will only be run once while your activity is active. You can see the documentation for `onCreate()` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)).

Comment: See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating) as well. This is just showing what methods get run when. You can see that onCreateView is run every time the fragment is reloaded like when you press the home navigation drawer option, but onCreate is only run when the fragment is first created.